# Android: Bug when changing the default activity

Tags: android, android-activity, default

I'm having a problem with my app after changing the default activity in the manifest. This is the manifest after i changed it. As far as i can see it's syntactically correct.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity android:name=".loginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="CouncilPlannerActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MainTabActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="MapTabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
    <activity android:name="NodeFormActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="viewNewsActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

The problem is when i deploy the app to my device it works fine first time. However, when i close the app with the home button it refuses to open again. Clicking the icon in the devices app list doesn't do anything.

If i change the default activity to the one it was at originally it works fine. Is this a bug or is there another reference to a default activity that i'm missing?

I'm developing on Android 2.2 if that makes a difference.

I just noticed the logcat spits out an error when i try to open the app : "Permission Denied: checkComponentPermission() reqUID10064"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to post the loginActivity in question here so we can see if there are any problems in the activity.  Otherwise double check that the loginActivity is in the same package as the other activities, if its not you need to change the ".loginActivity" part of the manifest to its relative location to the main package, aka "somename.loginActivity"

Comment: I found the solution after googling my error. Apparently the app was retaining the original default activity even though i'd changed the manifest. To fix it i had to completely remove the application from the device to remove any references to the default activity and then re-deploy the app. Thanks for the reply tho.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in loginActivity class. May be you check for already loggined user and finish activity in this case?